# Tracking a route to a point - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

guys, I'm new here, and I'm also new in Android programming. I'm working in an app about tourism in my city, showing some places of there. With the Api v2 of the Android, I'm showing the place that I want, but I just would like to track a simple route from my current position to this place. Could you help to resolve this problem? Thank you very much.

My Java Code:

```
    package com.readytogo;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class Hotel3MapActivity extends Activity{

private GoogleMap map;
private LatLng point = new LatLng(-19.91906 , -43.93857);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel3mapa);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    Marker pointTest = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Promenade Ianelli"));

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 15));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

 }
```

My XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: hi did you found helful my answer

Answer (score 0):

this is complete demo that all you want

https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/blob/master/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/docs/part6.md